# How to calculate average working days of closed tickets?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

So, I am new to Power BI and my database is a bit weird. it looks like this:

```
Ticket     Open Date       Close Date
BR001      02/01/2020      02/01/2020
BR001      02/01/2020      10/01/2020
BR001      12/02/2020      14/02/2020
BR002      02/02/2020      04/02/2020
BR002      05/02/2020
```

The reason it looks like this is that because some tickets are reopened up to 5-6 times. If the last row of the ticket does not contain a closing date, it means the ticket is still open for the time being. The result that would be ideal to me (I don't know if it's even possible) is to have 8 working average days for the first ticket in a matrix or table (excluding weekends) and not taking into account the second ticket since it's still open.

The desired output should look something like:

```
Ticket    Average working days
BR001     8 Days
BR002     null
```

Is it possible to have a result like that? Or what would be the closest thing to it? I am also open to transform the data with M-Query.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Explain- how it is 8 for first ticket. And where from you get the list of weekends?

Comment: Can you provide the desired output as a table? I'm not sure if that's is clear enough.

Comment: it should be 8 because the first line is one day, the second of January, then from the second till the tenth it should be 8 days, but on the calendar there are 2 days weekends, so it's technically 6 days. Since the first line started with the 2nd of January and ended the same day, and the second line started with the 2nd again, it should be counted as one day, not two. Then finally there are the two days in February which makes a total of 8 days. I hope that's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

First we add a column to the table:

```
DaysOpen = DATEDIFF(Tickets[Open Date], Tickets[Close Date], DAY)
```

This is simply doing a countdiff in days between open & close. Next we calculate the dayx of the weekends in a new column:

```
WeekendDays = 
var overRun = WEEKDAY(Tickets[Close Date], 2) - MOD(Tickets[DaysOpen], 7)
var lastWeekend = if (overRun < 0, -overrun, 0)
return  lastWeekend + ROUNDDOWN(Tickets[DaysOpen]/ 7, 0) * 2
```

There are 2 aspect: Calculate how many weekend we have for sure by dividing by 7 and multiply this by 2.
Check if there are days left which fall in weekend. I called it overrun.

Then we calculate the workdays:

```
WorkingDays = Tickets[DaysOpen] - Tickets[WeekendDays]
```

to summarize it all we create a new table:

```
TicketAveOpen = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(Tickets, not ISBLANK(Tickets[DaysOpen])),Tickets[Ticket],"TotalDaysOpen", SUM(Tickets[WorkingDays]))
```